# collections (Ranged Ops Integer Set)

Tags: java

Help please, how can I implement it so that it looks exactly like this
boolean add(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)
boolean remove(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)

```
RangedOpsIntegerSet set = new RangedOpsIntegerSet();
set.add(1, 5);
for(Integer el : set){
    System.out.println(el); // --> result 1,2,3,4
}
```

if i^m removed

```
RangedOpsIntegerSet set = new RangedOpsIntegerSet();
set.add(1, 15);
set.remove(3, 12);
for(Integer el : set){
    System.out.println(el); // result --> 1, 2, 12, 13, 14
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for someone to implement the `RangedOpsIntegerSet` class for you? If not, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: yes, but i cant understand how i can this implement

Comment: You need to try yourself. No one is going to just write code for you. If you don't show effort, eventually other people will downvote your question and eventually it will be closed.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a potential solution:

```
public class RangedOpsIntegerSet extends TreeSet<Integer> {
    
    public boolean add(int start, int end) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            boolean temp = add(i);
            if (!temp) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public boolean remove(int start, int end) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            boolean temp = remove(i);
            if (!temp) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RangedOpsIntegerSet set = new RangedOpsIntegerSet();
        set.add(1, 5);
        for (Integer num : set) {
            System.out.print(num + ",");
        }
        
        System.out.println();

        set.add(1, 15);
        set.remove(3, 12);
        for (Integer num : set) {
            System.out.print(num + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output this code produces based on your requirements:

```
1,2,3,4,
1,2,12,13,14,
```

THAT SAID, since this is most likely a homework, you might not be allowed to use an implementation of Java `Set` like I did here. Your teacher probably wants you to use an array to store the values. If that is the case, you will need to edit this to use solution using an array of `ints`. I warn you, this will be a bit more difficult because arrays don't grow dynamically.

Another advantage of using Java's `Set` API is that `remove()` will not throw an exception if your `start` or `end` values are out of range. The method simply returns `false` if the value you are trying to remove is not part of the collection. If you change this implementation using arrays, you have to account for out of range values.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you have correctly pointed out what needs to be done on the basis of arrays. I did as you threw it off, but my tests do not pass. I apologize for poorly pointing out the essence of the assignment

Comment: add (single-value) - adds a single value into the set // 
remove (single-value) - removes a single value from the set // 
add (ranged) - adds a range of values into the set (first argument - inclusive, last argument - exclusive). Return true if any of range values were actually added. // 
remove(ranged)- removes a range of values from the list (first argument - inclusive, last argument - exclusive). Return true if any of range values were actually removed. // 
iterator - iterates over elements of the set in natural order. //
size - returns the number of current queue elements

Comment: If you use this solution, `add(single_value)` and `remove(single_value)` methods already exist. If you need an array-based solution, you will have to write that yourself. I don't have the time to do that. But, I can tell you that you will have to create an array of `ints` as a global variable and when you call any of the `add()` methods, you will need to 1) figure out if the array has space to add the values. You can google for "dynamic array in Java" and copy those recommendations to figure out how to grow the array. Then...

Comment: ... you will need to add your new value (or values), and LASTLY you will need to sort the array. For removing, you can't just go by index location because your values will not necessary match your index locations. Therefore, you will iterate through the entire array and compare if the current value is "in range". I suggest you write a method to determine if a given value is in the range of the two given parameters.

Comment: @sqrtt one last thing.. if your solution must be array-based, I assume the underlying array has to be sorted. So, if you call `set.add(single_value)` it will need to add to the end and then sort the array. Otherwise, the ranged `remove()` function will have to iterate through the entire array to remove items because there will be no way of knowing where the "ranged" values are located.

Comment: I slept for a couple of hours, it's hard to combine my studies with two jobs. And looked closely at -> extends TreeSet<Integer> . And then I understood how to do it. Did. Thank you for telling me so cool

Comment: @sqrtt I worked full time and went to school full time and I had a wife and little kids. I know how you feel. Maybe when I get home tonight I will modify this answer to include an array-based solution. No promises though.

Comment: I modified the code to return `boolean`. One word of advice: for ranged remove, it is tricky to return boolean. A result of `false` means that the value being removed was not present in the set. For a range removal, it means that at least one value didn't exist before. You will not know which value wasn't present, but it doesn't matter because the end result is the same. For insertion, it means the value you want to add is already there. Since sets don't allow duplicates, it returns false. For range inserts, at least one value was already in the set. So, `false` doesn't matter either.

Comment: Thank you very much, you explained very clearly !